# send mail() php function to send e-mails in spanish encoding

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to send e-mails with the following mail function but I wish the encoding to show spanish characets as well. How I can make the `$email_body` to show them in the state in which is right now it is not working:

```
$email_body = "body text"; 

$headers = 'From: ' . $m . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $m . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\n\r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay Added the following line and now it is working: `$email_body = mb_convert_encoding($email_body, "ISO-8859-1","AUTO");`