# Separate string on a new line from mail function

Tags: php

Hello I have this kind of variable inside a mail function, but I wuld like to separate the text inside the string with diferent lines:

```
$email_body = "Dear Client,

Text Title one

Text Title on a new line
";
```

the final result inside the e-mail shuld be every line inside a new line.
right now everything is inside the same line when I perform:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating A New Line In $body Of PHP Mail Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782119/creating-a-new-line-in-body-of-php-mail-function)

Comment: have you tried the newline character '\n'?

Comment: Make sure your headers do not contain `Content-Type: text/html` (since I don't see full code)

Comment: After looking through your other questions, found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19546555/1415724) which contains `$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";` - so, if this is related, you will need to use the `\n` character for new lines, or use any of the examples given to you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `nl2br` PHP function to see the newlines, like this :

```
mail($to,$email_subject,nl2br($email_body),$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `html` and your desired `inline css` for your email template.

```
$email_body = "<html><body>";

$email_body. = "Dear Client,</br>";

$email_body. = "Text Title one,</br>";

$email_body. = "Text Title on a new line,</br>";

$email_body. = "</body></html>";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```